Splitting a .dmp file using Powershell
I'm trying to split a very large .dmp file using powershell.  I've found a variety of solutions online that split different types of files, but none for powershell that work on .dmp files.  Does something like this exist?

What's the purpose of "splitting" it? Are you trying to transfer it over a connection that limits file size or similar? Have you considered compression?

The files compressed are 4 GB which is way too large to be uploaded where they need to go.

Does this answer your question? In Powershell, How do I split a large binary file?

If you just need to dissassemble the file locally and then re-assemble it on the remote: read through the file stream on disk and copy each X MB chunk to a new file (where X is the maximum upload size of whatever transport you're using), then concatenate them to a single file on the remote side

I've used WinZip/WinRAR to compress and split the files into "X" mb sized files. While manually splitting the file into multiple "raw" chunks is "ok" (see @Hugo comment); the benefit (besides compression) is that WinZip/WinRAR will do integrity checks and use Checksums to ensure that when you go to decompress/reassemble everything, it ensures that 1. You have all the files, and 2. It was transferred properly. We had multi-GB files split into 300 separate 100MB files and FTP'd. Using WinZip/WinRAR, it was much easier to identify corrupt files and resend a single 100MB file rather than GB files
